# Inserting title into Access report based on multiple conditions

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba, case-statement

I am working on a report that will, through a form, allow multiple filters and a sort. I would like the title of the report to reflect the selections made for the filters & sort.

The report can be filtered by 3 fields: Product Type, Deliverables Received (yes/no) and Project Manager.

It can be sorted by: Contract number, Product Type, Contractor, TO Begin Date, TO End Date & Date Product Received

I have gotten some elements to work (Those where DeliverablesReceived have been selected with and without sorting) but am running into issues with the rest.

```
Public Function InsertTitle(strReportName As String) As String
Dim strProduct As String

If strReportName = "rptMasterDeliverables" Then
    If strField = "" Then
        InsertTitle = "All Deliverables Sorted by Project Manager"
    ElseIf Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived Like "No" Then
       InsertTitle = "Outstanding Deliverables Sorted by " & Left(strField, InStr(1, strField, ",") - 1) & ""
    ElseIf Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived Like "Yes" Then     
        InsertTitle = "Received Deliverables Sorted by " & Left(strField, InStr(1, strField, ",") - 1) & ""
    ElseIf InStr(1, strField, ",") = 0 Then                                      
        InsertTitle = "All Deliverables Sorted by " & strField & ""
```

The above all work well, I run into problems with the following

```
    ElseIf Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived Like "Yes" And Left(strField, 1) = "," Then
        InsertTitle = "Received Deliverables sorted by Project Manager"
    ElseIf Left(strField, 1) = "," And Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived Like "No" Then   'cboReceived
        InsertTitle = "Outstanding Deliverables sorted by Project Manager"
    ElseIf InStr(1, strProduct, ",") = 0 And Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived Like "No" Then
        InsertTitle = "" & Mid([strProduct], 2, Len([strProduct])) & " Deliverables"
    ElseIf Left(strField, 1) = "*" And InStr(1, strField, ",") = 0 Then
        InsertTitle = "All " & Mid([strField], 2, Len([strField])) & " Deliverables sorted by " & strField & ""
    ElseIf Left(strField, 2) = "* " And Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived Like "Yes" Then
        InsertTitle = "Received " & Mid([strField], 3, Len([strField])) & " Deliverables sorted by Project Manager"
```

The code for opening the report is

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strProducts As String
strField = "" 
    If CurrentProject.AllForms("fdlgMasterDeliverables").IsLoaded Then
    If Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboSort) Then
        Me.Report.GroupLevel(0).ControlSource = Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboSort.Column(0)      
        strField = Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboSort.Column(1)                                 
    If Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived) Then
        strField = strField & "," & Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived.Column(1)
    End If
    ElseIf Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived) Then           
        strField = "," & Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboDeliverableReceived.Column(1)    
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProductType) Then
        strProduct = Forms!fdlgMasterDeliverables!cboProductType.Column(1)
    End If
```

Currently the section that works properly returns "outstanding/received/all deliverables sorted by [selected sort]" and if no filters or sort are selected it properly returns "all deliverables sorted by project manager"

I am attempting to have the title return with the filter(s) identified. for instance if I choose Product type = "Document" & Product Manager = "Laura" I would like the title to read something like "all documents deliverables by Laura" If I add received = "no", I would like it to read "Outstanding document deliverables by Laura"

If I select Received = "Yes" & Product type = "Data" and choose to sort by contract number I would like the title to read "Received Data Deliverables by Contract Number"

If there is no sort order selected I would like the title to default to ".... sorted by Project Manager"

I have considered going to a Case statement but have no idea where to begin. Any insight into what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I should note that the report performs great, all filters work as do the sorts...it is just inserting the title that has me going insane

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting/seeing?  it looks like your code is missing pieces, can you post all of it, with the result your are getting vs the expected behaviour?